# Is async pipe broken in Angular2 beta8 and beta9?

Tags: pipe, angular

I tried the example on Angular2 official website: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

No message is displayed and without showing any error.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
// Initial view: "Message: "
// After 500ms: Message: You are my Hero!"
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-message',
  template: 'Message: {{delayedMessage | async}}',
})
export class HeroAsyncMessageComponent {
  delayedMessage:Promise<string> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('You are my Hero!'), 500);
  });
}
```

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/SokJZ8cGGx4upIaG7wW8?p=catalogue

Comment: I can see that you edited the plnkr 3 mins ago to match my answer... now it's working...

Answer (score 2):

You missed the constructor

```
export class AppComponent {
    data: Promise<string>;

    constructor() { // << You missed it!
        this.data = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(() => resolve("Hello World "), 500);
        });
    }
}
```

Or you can also assign directly the Promise to the property

```
    data: Promise<string> = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(() => resolve("Hello World "), 500);
    });
```

Here's your [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RbCZepiivr0QMJjTsFVR?p=preview) working.